# Show only diff when ASSERT_STREQ fails

Tags: c++, googletest

When googletest's `ASSERT_STREQ` fails , it prints both input strings and their diff. Can I make it print only the diff?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why? You might write your own matcher - and use it in `ASSERT_THAT(actualString, 
StringMatchShowingOnlyDiff(expectedString));` ...

Answer (score 3):

Using only GTest functionality? Not to my knowledge.

But nothing stops you from writing your own comparison function, i.e.

```
bool stringsMatch(std::string oneString, std::string otherString)
{
    //...
};

std::string getDifferencesBetween(std::string oneString, std::string otherString)
{
    //...
};
```

and then writing

```
//...
if (!stringsMatch(actualString, expectedString))
{
    FAIL() << getDifferencesBetween(actualString, expectedString);
}
//...
```